How to modify the output of $PATH in Linux
How can I modify the output of $PATH from
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/root/bin

to
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin


If you're running this as the root user, then having /root/bin on the end is acceptable. If you run it as a normal user you should find you don't get that part (but you might get /home/shahriar/bin or something similar instead)

The answer to your question depends on what you're trying to do, or what problem you're trying to solve with the change.  Can you elaborate more?

I guess it should be
PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin'

For temporary
export PATH

For permanent add the above $PATH line in your ~/.bashrc file

@ChrisDavies noted, thanks for the edit

Thank you for the information.  Would the following work ?
echo "PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin'" >> ~/.bashrc
Then, reboot

@ShahriarFlamneco Rebooting is not necessary. Log out and back in again, close your window and re-open, and . ~/.bashrc will all work just as well. And on any well-managed system, if you are not root you should not be able to access any files in /root/bin so having that in the PATH is not a problem.

Thank you very much for your help.
